# JLabel not showing up on JPanel in an Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

What I am trying to do is add a JLabel to a JPanel which is inside an applet. However, I cannot seem to get the JLabels to appear. I think my problem is where I am adding my Jlabels and I am not "refreshing the screen" and they are not visible.

Edit picture of what I see:[Picture of the panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grg7k.png)

Here is the code: **Main.java**

```
public class Main extends JApplet{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6568278275823927953L;

    public void init() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createGUI();
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("createGUI did not complete!");
        }
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz();
        Options myOption = new Options();

        JLabel[] answers = new JLabel[16];
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            answers[i] = new JLabel();
            answers[i].setText("HI!");
            answers[i].setOpaque(true);
            myOption.add(answers[i]);
        }
        myQuiz.setOpaque(true);
        myOption.setOpaque(true);
        this.add(myQuiz);
        this.add(myOption);
    }
}
```

**Options.java**

```
public class Options extends JPanel
         implements MouseListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3701573579935678995L;

Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20);
GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(4,4);
int HALF_WIDTH = getWidth() / 2;
int HALF_HEIGHT = getHeight() / 2;

public void init() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    this.setLayout(myLayout);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work okay for me.  Possible an issue with the `Quiz` pane? [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It also works for me also.

Comment: It probably is the quiz panel then, in there all I am doing is using the paint method to draw onto the screen. Could the quiz panel cover up the questions panel if nothing is in it?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).